# Gitlab CI - SSH Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: ssh, gitlab-ci

I've been trying to setup CD for my project. My Gitlab CI runner and my project will be on same server. I've followed https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/deployment/composer-npm-deploy.html but I keep getting `SSH Permission denied (publickey,password).` error. All my variables, private key and other variables set correctly in project settings.

I've created my ssh key with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my.email@example.com" -b 4096` command with no passphrase and set my `PRODUCTION_PRIVATE_KEY` variable with content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file.

This is my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  image: tetraweb/php
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add <(echo "$PRODUCTION_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
    - apt-get install rsync
  script:
    - ssh $PRODUCTION_SERVER_USER@$PRODUCTION_SERVER
    - hostname
  only:
    - master
```

And this is output from Gitlab CI runner:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.2.0 (adfc387)
  on ci-test (1eada8d0)
Using Docker executor with image tetraweb/php ...
Using docker image sha256:17692e06e6d33d8a421441bbe9adfda5b65c94831c6e64d7e69197e0b51833f8 for predefined container...
Pulling docker image tetraweb/php ...
Using docker image tetraweb/php ID=sha256:474f639dc349f36716fb98b193e6bae771f048cecc9320a270123ac2966b98c6 for build container...
Running on runner-1eada8d0-project-3287351-concurrent-0 via lamp-512mb-ams2-01...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at dfdb499 Update .gitlab-ci.yml
Checking out dfdb4992 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 12
$ ssh-add <(echo "$PRODUCTION_PRIVATE_KEY")
Identity added: /dev/fd/63 (rsa w/o comment)
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
$ apt-get install rsync
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
rsync is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$ ssh $PRODUCTION_SERVER_USER@$PRODUCTION_SERVER
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Warning: Permanently added '{MY_SERVER_IP}' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add the public key to the server so it would be recognized as an authentication key.

Comment: I use gitlab from gitlab.com. In this case by server we mean gitlab.com right? I have already added public key to my account. Should I add public key via gitlab-ci.yml? If so, how? Thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: No. I am talking about the `$PRODUCTION_SERVER`.

Comment: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and it works. Thanks!

Comment: ```cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys``` will overwirte already added keys. Use ```~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys```

Comment: Question: Based on what do you choose your image to be `image: tetraweb/php`, @kursat?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to add the public key to the server so it would be recognized as an authentication key. This is, paste the content of the public key corresponding to the private key you are using to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the `$PRODUCTION_SERVER`.

Comment: But how will we get public key of the created private ssh key on gitlab runner?

Comment: @JainamJhaveri - I thought this too, you copy the public key of the production server to its own authorized_keys since you are using the servers private key over on gitlab. (needs to be a public/private pair)

Answer (score 4):

This is the script that worked to me:

```
before_script:
                - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
                - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
                - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                - chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
                - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                - ssh-keyscan -t rsa 64.227.1.160 > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
                - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
                - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

And I had to unprotect the variable as well.

[image: Gitlab pipelines ssh key]

Answer (score 2):

Add the public key (corresponding to the private key) to authorized keys.

Just a new line with you pub key:

```
cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And also add the pub key to gitlab ssh keys section *Profile > Keys*

Answer (score 1):

Something important too...
The permissions of the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file should be 600.

Answer (score 1):

The following can be used alternatively

```
some_stage:
        - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
        - cd ~
        - touch id.rsa
        - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > id.rsa
        - chmod 700 id.rsa
        - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i id.rsa $SSH_USER@$SERVER
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be due to restrictions on users you can ssh into.

In my case, on the server, I got the following `tail -f /var/log/auth.log`:

```
..
Sep  6 19:25:59 server-name sshd[7943]: User johndoe from WW.XX.YY.ZZ not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups
..
```

The solution consists in updating the `AllowGroups` directive on the server's file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
AllowGroups janesmith johndoe
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we were clueless until we add the flag **-v** to the SSH command (we knew the public key setup was OK because we were able to connect to this instance from our laptop using the private key).

We saw this :

```
debug1: Offering public key: ... RSA SHA256:... agent
95debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
```

And understood the situation thanks to the two links below : our key was generated with RSA format which is considered legacy on up-to-date openssh versions.

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssh-rsa-key-rejected-with-message-no-mutual-signature-algorithm-1026057701.html
- https://transang.me/ssh-handshake-is-rejected-with-no-mutual-signature-algorithm-error/

So you have two solutions :

- generate a new key using ed25519 format and setup the public key on your instance
- use this extra flag below in your ssh command

It should be a temporary workaround :

```
ssh -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no your_user@your_instance_url "your command"
```

I hope it can help you if you are reading this.

Regards!

Comment: `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa` configuration directive in `~/.ssh/config` (for given host) solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Generate an SSH key pair on your local computer if you haven't already done so. You can use the ssh-keygen command for this:

ssh-keygen

This will create a key pair, one private (id_rsa) and one public (id_rsa.pub) in the ~/.ssh/ directory of your user.

Copy your public key on your local computer (id_rsa.pub) to the remote machine (VM). You can use the ssh-copy-id command to do this:

ssh-copy-id user@address_ip_vm

Make sure to replace user with your username on the remote machine and hostname with the IP address or domain name of the remote machine. The ssh-copy-id command will automatically add your public key to the authorized_keys file of the remote user.

You should now be able to connect to the remote machine without a password using SSH. You can test this by running the following command:

ssh user@hostname

You should be connected without having to enter a password. GitLab deployement can connect without password

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).