# SSH Connection issue from gitlab alpine runner

Tags: ssh, gitlab, vps, alpine-linux, cicd

I'm facing a problem with gitlab ci.
I have a `deploy` stage that is supposed to contact my VPS with ssh and asking my gitlab registry.

The problem is while y try to authenticate my alpine runner to my ssh.
here is my deploy :

```
deploy:
  tags:
    - springVps
  image: alpine:3.6
  stage: deploy

  before_script:
   - apk update
   - 'which ssh-agent || ( apk update -y && apk add openssh-client -y )'
   - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
   - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
   - echo "$SSHVPS" | ssh-add -
   - ssh-keyscan -H myawesomedomain.fr >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:  
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -p 51 -v -v -v root@myawesomdomain.fr "echo Hello, world!"
```

I've found this piece of code here : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/-/issues/4#note_35042568

Here is my error message : **SSH Permission denied (publickey,password)**

> note : i changed my ssh port from 22 to 51 but i had the same problem
> before.

Searched my error code and i found this post : [Gitlab CI - SSH Permission denied (publickey,password)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363537/gitlab-ci-ssh-permission-denied-publickey-password)

I don't totally understand the Accepted answer :

> You need to add the public key to the server so it would be recognized
> as an authentication key. This is, paste the content of the public key
> corresponding to the private key you are using to the
> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the $PRODUCTION_SERVER.

Does that mean i'm supposed to put my vps public key inside `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` ?
I executed the following command line on my vps : `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Now my `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` contain my vps public key, but that does not fixed my issue.
I've Also verified that my variable `$SSHVPS` has good value, i've tried to put the variable as file, and as variable, the variable is not portected. I've registered my vps public key inside gitlab.

Then i tried to connect to my vps from Local machine with this command line : `ssh -i key root@myawesomedomain.fr -p 51`

and this command ask me a password, it does not seems normal that it ask me a password.
I guess that is the reason of failing, my vps asks my alpine runner a password, but it is not supposed to.

I've made a lot of Search and its could be a permission mistake. I've found thoses command line to make `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` Readable and editable.

Here is that i tried :

```
chmod -v 700 ~ 
chmod -v 700 ~/.ssh
chmod -v 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

But i still have the same issue.
I' running out of ideas, any help is welcome ;)
Thanks for reading :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update :

Omg i just found what was my issue.
I cant clearly explain what happened but i will tell you what has going wrong.

I created a new user named "ftpuser" to connect to my ftp, but for some reasons when i login to my vps with root user, the permissions has been set for ftpuser in root folder i could have seen this with this command :  `ls -la ~` and also :  ls -`la ~/.ssh`

I cant explain why and how connecting to root i had ftpuser permissions but i solved the issue on this way :  `chown -R root:root ~`  `chown -R root:root ~/.ssh`  `chown -R root:root ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

you can see here the mistake :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just did this using the secret-as-a-file (which is one of the options you seem to have studied, but of course it will also work with the secret-as-variable). But I think it is easier, as e.g. it does not need ssh-agent running:

```
 before_script:
    - chmod 400 $ID_RSA
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  script:
    - rsync -avz --rsh="ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" my_output/html $WEBSITE_USER@$WEBSITE_SERVER:/var/www/html/enablement/.
```

of course, the script can be also just

```
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $WEBSITE_USER@$WEBSITE_SERVER echo hello world
```

However, on your remote VPS Server you need to do the following things, and it is important that you do it FOR THE USER you are using to connect with ssh. In your example "root" but it can be any other (dedicated) user:

```
echo $MY_PUB_KEY >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

(at least the first you did)

If this does not work there are other problem that may occur. Make sure:

- your ssh key is PASSWORDLESS for this purpose
- your ssh key uses cipher etc. compatible with ssl, typically RSA

The ssh command must work from any linux shell (or container). So you can test the command and setup without the more complicated CI setup.

Comment: Hello i tried you script but i have same error  : `Warning: Permanently added '[mydomainname.fr]:51,[myipaddress]:51' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).`

if i try to connect on another shell, the machine will not have his public key on my vps ? So it wont work or i missed something ? even tring to connect with my local machine it asks me password

I did the command lines on the right user and i have rsa key

Comment: If you have your private key in ssh.key, please make sure that `ssh-keygen -y -f ssh.key` works and does NOT require a password.

Comment: if i put this command on my vps the print out is my public key and when i do it on my local PC it tell me : `bad permissions. Try removing permissions for user: BUILTIN\\Users (S-1-5-32-545) on file C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/something.
WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!
Permissions for 'key' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "key": bad permissions`

Comment: Ok, so you must set the file permissions, too. Do `chmod 600 ssh.key`.

Comment: okay with `chmod 600 key` and `ssh-keygen -y -f key`  it also give me my vps's public key from my local pc.

Comment: In this case check that 'ssh -i ssh.key  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@server.fr' works with no password and  no question asked.

Comment: It's still ask me a password

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252715/discussion-between-jean-moulin-and-ralf-ulrich).

Comment: If ssh-keygen does not ask a password, but ssh does then very likely the server is misconfigured. Login to the server and check /etc/ssh/sshd_config contains "PubkeyAuthentication Yes" and the most important is that your pub key is in /root/.ssh/authorized_keys AND set the permissions correct also here: chmod 700 ~/.ssh and
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. Finally, please post the full verbose log output of ssh -v here, for sure it contains info on what is going wrong.

Comment: Okay i added PubkeyAuthentication Yes and i set up all the chmod with good configuration but its still ask me a password ); you can see the errors logs here : https://justpaste.it/ch2rp Thanks